# UIScrollView using Autolayout will only bounce

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, uistoryboard

I am really struggling to get a UIScrollView to work correctly with Autolayout. Instead of scrolling down as it should, it just bounces, so if I drag it to see more as soon as I let go it returns to its original position.

I have my scene set up in the following way:
-Main View
 - Scroll View
  - Content View
   - Label
   - Label

The View Controller has its size metric set to Freeform. The Main View, Scroll View and Content View all have their Height set to 700, so I can see the layout correctly.

In my .h file I have an outlet connected to the UIScrollView and in my viewDidLoad method I am doing the following:

```
Scroller.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
[self.Scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];
```

I've tried setting all sorts of constraints, on various things. Normally when I add a new one Xcode then grumbles that the constraints are incorrect and prompts me to update them. I have tried so many different variations, I can't remember them all but here are a few:

1. Pinning the height of the Scroll View
2. Pinning the bottom of the Content View to the Scroll View - [Getting UIScrollView to work with AutoLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19898656/getting-uiscrollview-to-work-with-autolayout)
3. Pinning the height of the Content View

Other things I have tried:

1. Reading & following Apple's Technote: - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html
2. Setting the ScrollView's Content Inset - [Confusion Regarding UIScrollView and AutoLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210838/confusion-regarding-uiscrollview-and-autolayout)
3. Setting the Content Size: [UIWebView's UIScrollView subview can scroll but bounce back to the frame without appearing vertical scroll indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19832098/uiwebviews-uiscrollview-subview-can-scroll-but-bounce-back-to-the-frame-without)

I'm sure this must be relatively straight forward, but I have been tearing my hair out. There are many similar questions on Stackoverflow and Google, but none of them seem to fully meet my requirements.

Any help or resources would be greatly appreciated.

JA

Comment: Have you checked contentSize value after layout event, for example in viewDidAppear?

Comment: It's 0.000000. Why would that be if it is set to 1000.000000 in the View Did Load?

Comment: All seems to work fine if I move [self.Scroller setContentSize:...] from the viewDidLoad method to the viewDidAppear one. I don't understand why though, viewDidLoad should be called when it's first created, right?

Comment: layout event happens after viewDidLoad. Likely you have problems in you constrains/autoresize mask

Comment: Yes, viewDidLoad happens right after the view has been created, it is not even added to the view hierarchy at this stage. layoutSubviews happens after that, each time system decides to do layout

Comment: Yeah, I just put the code in the viewDidLayoutSubviews method and it's looking pretty good. I have cleared all of the restraints in the View Controller so I don't think they can be the problem. Should I be worried about the autoresize mask? Or can I safely assume I'm ok?

Comment: I am afraid I'm not of much help here. Personally I create content view programmatically and do not use constrains/autoresize mask with it. If you want to be completely sure you have research this or wait other answers.

Comment: I'll do some research! Thanks very much for your help, I needed it! If you want to create an answer I can assign you the rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible reason for this is that scroll view's contentSize is reset after layout event which happens after viewDidLoad (for example due to incorrect constrains settings).

Answer (score 2):

I had to put the code in viewDidAppear for it to work right

```
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(320, 931);
    self.scroller.scrollEnabled = YES;
    self.scroller.contentSize = size;
```